# Firebase Storage package not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase storage service to upload image on my Android app, everything was working fine. but suddenly my code is giving the errors below and doesn't allow me to run the project again. any idea ?

1st error

[image: 1st error]

2nd error

[image: 2nd error]

Comment: check ur app's build.gradle file if the storage dependency is exists? error log says it does not exist. so add it.

Comment: yeah, make sure you have `com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:x.x.x` in the depedencies of `build.gradle` file

Comment: Thank you guys. But I already have the dependency and my code was working properly and I used the package but suddenly it started to give that error, the gradle is synchronised successfuly with no errors but I can't use Firebase library. Is Firebase limited for free using?